# OpenAM Policy Enforcement

Tags: jakarta-ee, openam

My test environment is comprised of openam 10.0.1, j2ee policy agent 3.1.0. When I set up a policy with a rule as follows:

```
host.example.com/testapp/*
```

Using URI Policy Agent, the rule gets enforced correctly (note the wild char `*` at the end). When I access a link

```
http://host.example.com/testapp/test/index
```

However, this is too coarse for my need. I need something like this:

```
host.example.com/testapp/test/*
```

For some reason this doesn't match correctly to a request such as

```
host.example.com/testapp/test/index
```

As a result the policy agent denies the request to the end user. Any clues on how to solve this issue?

The application in question is a grails application that has standard URI mapping of controller and action.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by configuring the agent policy itself. Click on the agent policy (in Access Control > [domain] > Agents tab > J2EE agents > [agent] and:

- Application tab: Not Enforced URI Processing section > add "/testapp/test/*"
- Application tab: Not Enforced URI Processing section > check the "Invert Not Enforced URIs" checkbox so that it will actually enforce the "Not Enforced URI" values

Answer (score 0):

Set debug level to 'message' in the agent profile first. Look into the agent debug log so that you really see which request the agent gets.

In general what you need is possible, just a matter of proper configuration.

-Bernhard